# Create a video from images unix command line with transitions

Tags: php, unix, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I found several questions with answers on how to create a video from images. I setup two of them and was able to produce the videos correctly. I tried the following:

**ImageMagick**
convert -delay 100 -quality 75 photo1.jpg photo2.jpg movie.mpg

**FFMPEG**
ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i photo1.jpg photo2.jpg movie.mpg

The end result is the video displaying images with timing, no effects. I looking to learn how they add a Fade In and Fade Out Transition between those images.

Comment: Heh, funny: Related: http://www.odesk.com/jobs/Images-to-slideshow-video-PHP-class-FFmpeg_~~394e676d2c71eef9?source=rss

Comment: Can do you do this sort of thing? Or did you post the Job itself?

Comment: neither, I just saw it while Googling and posted it out of an impulse. It's not really of value.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this can be done by either library out of the box, short of creating every frame one by one. Both libraries don't really  focus on Video effects.

One command line solution I can see is [dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page):

> dvd-slideshow is a group of Linux commandline programs that creates a slideshow-style dvd from groups of pictures. Slideshow videos can be made from a directory or some online photo albums. You can add fancy effects like fades, titles, and the Ken Burns effect (slowly zooming and panning at the same time) along with audio to make your slideshows even nicer. There is also a script which generates a menu for your dvd (dvd-menu). The dvd-slideshow tools are open-source programs released under the GNU GPL.

It can output DVD (MPEG-something) and FLV among other this. You may have to do two transitions, but you should be able to build any kind of video file using a combination of this and ffmpeg.