# Pile of images to video

Tags: linux, video, image

What's the best way of turning a pile of images into a video?

I'm on Linux, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are literally talking about single frames? Not turning photographs into a slide show?

If it's the former, [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) is a good bet.

- [3.2 How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14)

If you want to create a slide show, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174710/create-a-video-from-images-unix-command-line-with-transitions).

Comment: yeah, im literally talking about single frames, no slideshow.

The ffmpeg doesn't work. i have four images in my folder: 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg.
i type: ffmpeg -f image2 -i %d.jpg output_video.mpg
and the output video works only the first time i run it. all tries after the first try after rebooting the computer, fail.
is there any other method than this ffmpeg? i have very bad experience with ffmpeg, it never works and it has a very bad interface.

Comment: @Hermann have you tried a different output format like `mp4`? FFMpeg is kind of a standard in Video conversion on Linux... I don't know of any other. What kind of output format do you need exactly?

Comment: tried mp4, fails exactly the same way.
i just need any format that displays a video.

Comment: I would check out the data before dropping ffmpeg as a possibility. Are all the images RGB JPEG files? There couldn't be a CMYK file in the batch? Can you reproduce the problem with other JPG files?

Comment: i checked all files with the 'file' command, it confirms that they truly are jpg files. then i took completely different pictures and tried to do the same, same old error, a video file that takes up memory but displays nothing, is created.

Comment: @Hermann strange. Have you tried with different players? Do you have access to a second machine possibly?

Comment: it was the player.
kaffeine doesn't work with this... for some reason.
tried kmedia player, it worked but poorly. then tried codeine and that one just worked.

thanks!